# Entering secondary data into pre-existing database

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help.  I have written a script to put first and last name into a database.  This works correctly.  Then I have written a script to display these names along with 4 text fields per name where student points can by typed in and then stored in the DB.  The names from the DB are displayed correctly and the text fields display correctly however, when I try to put the numbers in the fields it does not put the numbers in the DB and generates "undefined index" errors.  I have worked on this for a while but am just not getting it.  Thanks for your help.  My code is below.  Thank you.

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="pts_summary.php" method="post">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Student Name</th>
<th>First Hour</th>
<th>Second Hour</th>
<th>Third Hour</th>
<th>Fourth Hour</th>
</tr>
<br>

<?php

$hour1 = $_POST['hour1'];
$hour2 = $_POST['hour2'];
$hour3 = $_POST['hour3'];
$hour4 = $_POST['hour4'];


$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","srrdb");                         
if (mysqli_connect_errno())                                                 
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * From students");                      


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))                                   
{
    echo "<tr>"."<td>".$row['fname']."&nbsp".$row['lname']."</td>".     
    "<td>".'<input type="text" name="hour1">'."</td>".                  
    "<td>".'<input type="text" name="hour2">'."</td>".                  
    "<td>".'<input type="text" name="hour3">'."</td>".                  
    "<td>".'<input type="text" name="hour4">'."</td>"."</tr>";          
}

if (isset ($_POST['submit']))
{
$sql="INSERT INTO students (hour1, hour2, hour3, hour4) 
VALUES ('".$hour1."','".$hour2."','".$hour3."','".$hour4."')";
}   

mysqli_close($con);                                                         

?>                                                                          

</table>
<br><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your form doesn't have any fields to post.

Comment: Jessica, I am not sure how you mean.  Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to grab post data before you even check if the submit button was pressed.  If the submit button wasn't pressed, you won't have values in any of the $_POST['hour#'] fields, and that will throw an undefined index error.  Throw those lines AFTER the submit check like so.

```
if (isset ($_POST['submit']))
{
    $hour1 = $_POST['hour1'];
    $hour2 = $_POST['hour2'];
    $hour3 = $_POST['hour3'];
    $hour4 = $_POST['hour4'];

    $sql="INSERT INTO students (hour1, hour2, hour3, hour4) 
    VALUES ('".$hour1."','".$hour2."','".$hour3."','".$hour4."')";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your undefined index notices are caused by using `$_POST[...]` without checking if they are set. Your data is not inserting into your database, as you are only setting the `INSERT` query -

```
$sql="INSERT INTO students...
```

but you never execute a query.

```
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

try -

```
if (isset ($_POST['submit'])){
    // put these inside isset() to prevent undefined index notices
    $hour1 = $_POST['hour1'];
    $hour2 = $_POST['hour2'];
    $hour3 = $_POST['hour3'];
    $hour4 = $_POST['hour4'];

    $sql="INSERT INTO students (hour1, hour2, hour3, hour4) 
    VALUES ('".$hour1."','".$hour2."','".$hour3."','".$hour4."')";
    //missing the query line
    // Insert or die with error message
    $update = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Also, you are using unsanitized `$_POST` data so you are open to SQL Injection. Either sanitize using [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or better yet use prepared statements -  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Sean, I modified my code as you suggested regarding isset() and my undefined index errors disappeared, thank you.  I then added the line $update = mysqli_query($con,$sql); but the date I have entered into the fields are still not posting to the DB.  I can't help but think I am not totally understanding how you meant for me to use the code in this line.  Would you mind elaborating?  Thanks again.

Comment: My guess is that your insert query is failing/erring out. This could be any number of reasons. Try adding [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to your update query. I have edited my answer with it.